# Combination problem : 6 Schools , three sports.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Six schools participate in a youth sports conference and each school is represented by three players a cricketer, a soccer player, and a hockey player.

It is required to select a committee of six members from among these players. Find the number of different ways in which this committee can be formed,

i)  if each from each sport must be included.

ii) if two players from each sport must be included, in such a way that all six schools are represented.

iii)    if two players each from two schools and one player each from two of the remaining schools must be included.

My attempts

i) 3375

iii)  7290

ii) For this one I got 90 as the answer.

I chose two schools out of 6, then 2 schools out of 4, then 2 out of 2.

$${6\choose 2}\times{4\choose 2}\times{2\choose 2}$$

Is there another different method to get this answer?  Not by selecting schools first.

Comment: Instead of just providing the numerical value, can you also state you reasoning for how you arrived at it?

Comment: Note: I reformatted this so that whole sentences appeared on the page without any scrolling.  I don't understand what condition $i)$ means though....it looks like you left a word off.  And I guess you mean this to be three separate questions, though you should say that explicitly.

Comment: The reasoning in (ii) seems valid. If in (i) you meant “if a player from each sport must be presented”, then I got a different answer. For me the hardest part was to understand what you meant in (iii), I failed completely.

Comment: Question (i) is unclear. If the question is "if a player from each sport must be included" then your answer is too low value. Questions (ii) and (iii) seem correct to me.